# Windows 10 taking too long to shut down completely

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

My Windows 10 Desktop Computer is taking too long to completely shut down, after I have clicked the Shut Down button. The problem has been continuing since about 4 months. Sometime earlier, I updated Windows to check if the problem is solved. However, it still continues. What are the possible ways to solve this problem, or atleast minimise the time taken?

Comment: So how long is it taking? Also, how much RAM do you have? HDD or SSD?

Comment: @gronostaj My PC has 8GB DDR3 RAM. Storage drive is HDD.

Comment: And how long is it taking to shut down?

Comment: @gronostaj In most cases, about three to four minutes. Sometimes, even longer.

Comment: Does a reboot take this long as well, longer or shorter? And how long does it take before your screen goes black vs the entire system turns off?

Comment: It's likely hanging due to the default time processes and services are given to stop - verify by enabling [verbose](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/enable-verbose-startup-shutdown-logon-logoff-status-messages) shutdown messages. While I'm not sure how to natively change the time period, you can do so via Yamicsoft's [Windows 10 Manager](https://yamicsoft.com/windows10manager/product.html) _(free full-use for 20days)_: _Optimizer_ → _System Speed_ → _Shutdown_. You can also enable verbose messages via: _Customization_ → _Custom System_ → _System_